# Can't find torrc file on Mac

Tags: configuration, mac

I just installed the TorBrowser (v. 6.0.1) on my mac (OS 10.11.5) - went to the torproject page and downloaded the installer for mac. I am seeing instructions online about changing my torrc file in order to set which country I want to exit the Tor network from, but I can't find a file called torrc.

I've tried "locate torrc" but it doesn't find a file. I did find torrc-defaults in /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor, but there's no plain old torrc file.

The Tor FAQ lists this:

> If you installed Tor Browser, look for
>   Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc inside your Tor Browser directory.
>   On OS X, you must right-click or command-click on the Tor Browser
>   icon, and select "Show Package Contents" before the Tor Browser
>   directories become visible.
>
> Tor puts the torrc file in /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc if you compiled
>   tor from source, and /etc/tor/torrc or /etc/torrc if you installed a
>   pre-built package.

I've looked in all those places and I'm not finding a file called torrc.

Comment: I also looked for a folder called "TorBrowser-Data" after seeing on another site that it might be the place to look, but I couldn't find that either.

Comment: I tryed this out, but it did not work. I still cannot find the torcc file... I looked for it mannually via navigating to "go" in the tab menu, hitting alt, selecting library, and so forth... I also tryed what it said on the TOR website. Nothing is working for me. please help. I need to access the torcc file to edit my proxy configurations manually...

Comment: For the case anyone else is looking: I installed Tor through Homebrew, and apparently the torrc-file is supposed to be located in */usr/local/etc/tor* when taking that path. There's none in my installation, but sample files are there, so I suppose it's a correct location.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found it.

~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/torrc

I got the info from a bug tracking ticket: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13252

Thanks to https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/12737/canonizing-ironize who gave a pointer to the ticket in the answer to another question.

Comment: Thank's! I was updating my script [Tor-ExitNode-changer](https://github.com/gmolop/Tor-ExitNode-changer) and can't figure out why stop working... Different `torrc` path was the cause. Fixed now.

Comment: TorBrowser-Data/torrc not present in Application support folder on mac sierra 10.12.2 and tor 6.5

Comment: I thought that too, but the folder was generate after I startet it the first time.

Comment: Slight change in Sierra, it is in `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc`

Comment: On Catalina (10.15.7), there does seem to be a torrc, but it is just 986 bytes & is not at all like what's given [https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in] here
Any clue where to find torrc. I did already try `sudo find \ -name torrc` & the only got:
`/System/Volumes/Data/Users/admin/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/` &
`/Users/admin/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/`

Neither had a torrc like the one in the sample :(
More info: 
Tor version 0.4.4.5 (git-24e808e946e741d0).
Tor Browser: 10.0.2

Comment: I was using tor service as proxy. In my case I had to edit my torrc file at `/usr/local/etc/tor` , the file name was torrc.sample I had to remove .sample and use that torrc file to see the changes in effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still curious why others find the TorBrowser-Data directory in ~/Library/Application Support/ while I have it in the same directory where I keep the TorBrowser.app (note same dir as the app *not* in the app bundle).  I've moved my TorBrowser-Data dir into ~/Library/Application Support/ but I still need a symlink in the app folder to get to it.  Otherwise launching the app just recreates a fresh copy of the TorBrowser-Data dir.

Maybe it has something to do with the fact I use Snow Leopard 10.6.7.  It doesn't really bother me other than I'm just curious in the difference in behavior from others.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured out what the app is doing.  It _does_ look for ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data when the app is placed in /Applications.  Otherwise it looks for (and creates if necessary) a TorBrowser-Data dir in the same dir as the app when the app is **not** located in /Applications.