# Configuration file in mac: socket port is configured in Library folder or application folder?

Tags: configuration, mac, terminal

I have torrc-default file and torrc custom file on mac at:

```
/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor
```

folder (the package of the app).

In both files it is specified:

```
SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
ControlPort 9151
```

But when I start tor from unix, it loads listening to 9050.

So I tried to look at configuration in [https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/11870]:

```
~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/torrc
```

and here I find :

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory /Applications/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Tor
```

**So, where does the port 9050 come from?**

[image]

---

EDITED after comment

I start the application from the folder where tor file is:
`/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor`.
That folder also contains `torrc` and `torrc-default` files.

I tried:

```
./tor -f torrc
```

and:

```
Oct 28 20:16:17.741 [notice] Tor v0.2.8.7 (git-263088633a63982a) running on Darwin with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1t and Zlib 1.2.5.
Oct 28 20:16:17.742 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Oct 28 20:16:17.757 [warn] Unable to open configuration file "/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/Tor/torrc".
Oct 28 20:16:17.757 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Answer (score 1):

9050 is a builtin default, from the [Tor Manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort)...

> **SocksPort** [address:]port|unix:path|auto [flags] [isolation flags]
>
> Open this port to listen for connections from SOCKS-speaking applications. Set this to 0 if you don’t want to allow application connections via SOCKS. Set it to "auto" to have Tor pick a port for you. This directive can be specified multiple times to bind to multiple addresses/ports. **(Default: 9050)**

When you're starting it "from unix", it's probably looking for the default torrc, not finding any defined in the builtin default location (you need to specify the location with `-f` and optional `--defaults-torrc` if it's not in the location it was told to look when it was compiled) and instead falling back to it's default settings.

Comment: Hi canonizing ironize (great nick!) - Please see updated question.

Comment: It looks like there's some kind of file permissions error, as far as it can tell the file doesn't exist, or at least `tor` can't access it. Does OSX do weird stuff with the `foo.app`, isn't it some kind of archive that needs to be specially handled? `tor` may not be able to handle it, it expects a plain file. My knowledge of OSX internals is limited as I've never used it before.

Comment: What happens if you just run `cat torrc` from the directory, for example? Do you see the file contents as expected? As far as I'm aware all that stuff should now be in the `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/` folder because there are issues with the OSX package signing when you edit the contents of the package. Writing Tor's state and any configuration settings out inside the `.app` will make the signature invalid. (This is my understanding, I don't so OSX or any Apple products.)

Comment: I can see the file with `cat torrc`. In `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/` there is a torrc file with datadirectory pointing to Application folders. It can't open it. Strange part is that if I run tor from terminal, it ignores torrc files and listen on 9050. If I run tor browser, it will read configuration file and listen also on number 9150.

Comment: It's not ignoring the torrc, it just can't open it for some reason. I'm unsure why, if Tor is running as the same user and your user can read it I don't see why the tor process can't. I'm assuming OS X quirks that I'm unaware of.