# torcc file missing on Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: configuration, stem, identity-change

Trying to get Tor to renew my identity for my Python code.

I'm following the [STEM project guide](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) on how to set this up. It seems that to get this properly working (for Python), I need to [edit the torrc file](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html).

However, I do not seem to have this torrc file. Its not located where it should be according to STEM, nor is it in the place according to [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/11870). In short, I just do not have this file.

Is this a common issue? Should I create the file myself, and if so, how? Should I download the file somewhere? Or is it something else?

Comment: The `torrc` files location depends on how it was built and installed and it can be defined when you start tor by using the `-f` command line option.

Comment: When I run `tor -f` in Terminal, I get `Command-line option '-f' with no value. Failing`. And when I run `tor --verify-config` I get `Configuration file "/opt/local/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.` I copied the `torrc.sample`, uncommented the necessary according to [the guide](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html) and renamed the copy `torrc`. That does not seem to work either. Sidenote: I placed this question and registered afterwards - I am not allowed to comment on the question. Let me know I I can appoint this question to my account

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Finder
2. Press Command, Shift, G
3. Enter this command: ~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor

You should be able to see the Torcc file